# Azure Cloud Service: two web roles sharing the same port

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I would like to have a single Azure Cloud Service including two web applications. Both applications should have **the same inbound port number** (80) and differ in host headers only.

Is it possible to configure these applications as **different web roles**? As I see it's not possible to specify the same port as an endpoint of different roles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No this isn't possible. You have 2 options:

- Deploy everything to a **single** Web Role. [This allows you to use host headers on the same port.](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/02/running-multiple-websites-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/) If you think performance might be an issue, simply add more instances.
- If for some reason you can't host both web applications in a single Web Role, consider using multiple cloud services:

  - myapp1.cloudapp.net -> with host header: customers.myapp.com

    - WebRoleA with input endpoint Http port 80
  - myapp2.cloudapp.net -> with host header: admin.myapp.com

    - WebRoleB with input endpoint Http port 80

Comment: can i have mutliple cloud settings for multiple website on single webrole ?